# Accumulated sum of 2D array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray, numpy-einsum

Suppose I have a 2D numpy array like below

```
dat = np.array([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8])
```

I want to get a new array with each row equals to the sum of its previous rows with itself, like the following

```
first row: [1,2]
second row: [1,2] + [3,4] = [4,6]
third row: [4,6] + [5,6] = [9,12]
forth row: [9,12] + [7,8] = [16,20]
```

So the array would be like

```
dat = np.array([[1,2],[4,6],[9,12],[16,20])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[np.cumsum](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.cumsum.html#numpy.cumsum) is what you are looking for:

```
dat = np.array([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8]])
result = np.cumsum(dat, axis=0)
```